# How to add the alternate file name to the list(2 List) in C#

Tags: c#, list

I have list of files in the variable Files `var Files`

```
DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(dir);

var Files = info
  .GetFiles("*.txt")
  .Where(p => p.LastWriteTime.Date == DateTime.Today);
```

Example if I have 500 file name in the variable files. I need to add the alternate file name to the list. Inside the `for each`loop I need to add first file in container1 and 2nd file in container2 like that.

**List1:**
Container1 (it will add the 1st,3rd,5th file like this)

**List2:**
Container2 (it will add the 2nd,4th,6th file like this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *Linq*, and `GroupBy` intial `Files` into groups:

```
var Alternated = Files
  .Select((name, index) => new {name, index})
  .GroupBy(item => item.index % 2, item => item.name)
  .Select(group => group.ToList())
  .ToArray();

var list1 = Alternated[0];
var list2 = Alternated[1];
```

Or loop (no Linq solution)

```
var list1 = new List<FileInfo>();
var list2 = new List<FileInfo>();

var currentList = list1;

foreach (var item in Files) {
  currentList.Add(item);

  currentList = currentList == list1 ? list2 : list1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply try this. Any null checks etc exception handling have been left out.

```
var Files = info.GetFiles("*.txt")
        .Where(p => p.LastWriteTime.Date == DateTime.Today);

var list1 = Files.Where((file,index) => index % 2 != 0);
var list2 = Files.Where((file,index) => index % 2 == 0);
```

Comment: Here 'c' defines?

Comment: just changed it to more relevant